# C++ std::map named requirements allocator-aware container

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, stdmap

Currently I'm trying to convert some of C++'s named requirements to C++20 concepts (https://godbolt.org/z/EdY5d6319 still highly WIP!). However, I stumpled upon a problem.

Given the final C++20 working draft (http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf):

- page 790: requirements for an allocator-aware container: 
  Given an allocator-aware container X with value_type T the expression `a == t` where `a` denotes a non-const lvalue of type X and `t` an lvalue or const rvalue of type X is required. 
  Preconditions: T is Cpp17CopyInsertable into X and **Cpp17CopyAssignable**. 
  -> Therefore, `X::value_type` must be CopyAssignable.
- page 699: `is_copy_assignable`: 
  "For a referenceable type T, the same result as `is_assignable_v<T&, const T&>`, otherwise `false`."
- page 849: `std::map`: 
  "A map meets all of the requirements of a container, of a reversible container (22.2), of an associative
  container (22.2.6), and of an **allocator-aware container** (Table 76)."

So `std::map<Key, T>` meets the requirements of an allocator-aware container. Therefore, `std::map<Key, T>::value_type` must be CopyAssignable.
However, `std::map<Key, T>::value_type` is defined as `std::pair<const Key, T>`, which is **not** CopyAssignable due to `Key` beeing `const`.
Therefore, `std::map` does not meet the allocator-aware container requirements, which contradicts page 849 in the standard draft.

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's an explicit carve out for this case in [[containers.associative.reqmts]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/associative.reqmts#7):

> The associative containers meet all the requirements of Allocator-aware containers, except that for `map` and `multimap`, the requirements placed on `value_­type` in [Table 76](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/container.requirements.general#tab:container.alloc.req) apply instead to `key_­type` and `mapped_­type`. [ Note: For example, in some cases `key_­type` and `mapped_­type` are required to be *`Cpp17CopyAssignable`* even though the associated `value_­type`, `pair<const key_­type, mapped_­type>`, is not *`Cpp17CopyAssignable`*. — end note ]

Comment: Oh well thanks for the fast reply. I already thought, that I'm missing a special case. However, I thought that that case should appear in the `std::map` section and not before the allocator-aware requirements :D.

Comment: @Arkantos493: Don't feel bad; it's really hard to track STL stuff down in the standard. For any given container, there are at least 3 different places you might have to look to find something out about its behavior. Because repetition would be bad.