# Is there an inconsistency in the C++17 standard regarding std::map::iterator?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I am a bit confused about the C++17 standard named requirements regarding iterators; it seems to me that `std::map::iterator` violates the requirements. From the standard, I gather the following:

1. All container iterators are supposed to satisfy ForwardIterator.
2. For an iterator `It` satisfying ForwardIterator, `std::iterator_traits<It>::reference` has to be either `value_type&` – if `It` is mutable – or `const value_type&` – if `It` is constant.
3. The notion “`It` is mutable” is defined as “`It` also satisfies OutputIterator”, while “constant” means non-mutable.
4. In order to satisfy OutputIterator, the expression `*it = o` should be valid for `o` being of a type writable to the iterator; there has to be a nonempty set of such types.

Now, `std::iterator_traits<std::map::iterator>::reference` is `value_type&` (without `const`), but the iterator does not satisfy the OutputIterator requirements – as `value_type` of `map::iterator` is `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, we can never assign to `*it`.

So, the question is, am I overlooking some part of the standard that deals with this inconsistency? Or am I interpreting the standard requirements wrong?

Comment: i remember similar question (looking for the dupe). There are extra special cases for `std::map` in the standard.

Comment: I have tried searching stackoverflow for things like "map iterator forwarditerator outputiterator const" but I have not been successful in finding anything similar.

Comment: different question, but I think the answer applies here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67112813/c-stdmap-named-requirements-allocator-aware-container (at least it poitns to sections that specify the extra rules for map)

Comment: IMHO it is almost the same consistency as `vector<bool>` which violates almost all iterator requirements...

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I still don't see anything relevant in the [associative.reqmts] part of the standard.

Comment: yes the question is about slightly different aspect, though its not "All container...", but there are special cases. I thought the other answer can help to point in some direction. (I dont think it answers your quesiton, otherwise I would have closed as duplicate)